# Is using NaN as a default value in Redux a bad practice?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flowtype

I have a reducer that stores data received from API endpoint at some point in the app:

```
export type Payments = {|
  +cycle_length: number,
  +next_billing_date: string,
  +paid_for_users: number,
  +payment_method: number,
  +is_trial: boolean,
  +plan: number,
  +price: string,
  +status: string,
  +subscription_id: string,
  +team: number,
|};

const INITIAL_STATE: Payments = {
    cycle_length: NaN,
    next_billing_date: '',
    paid_for_users: NaN,
    payment_method: NaN,
    plan: NaN,
    is_trial: false,
    price: '',
    status: '',
    subscription_id: '',
    team: NaN,
};
```

Because I'm also using `Flow` type-checker NaN value seemed to be proper initial value as they don't raise an error like `null` or `undefined`.

So far I thought that everything is fine.

But today I came across and issue. I've had this implementation of `componentWillReceiveProps` in component:

```
componentWillReceiveProps({ creatingSubscriptionError, changingTeamPlanError, targetPlan, history, subscription }) {
    if (creatingSubscriptionError || changingTeamPlanError) {
      history.push('/payments/failure');
    } else {
      const hasChangedPlan = this.props.subscription.plan !== subscription.plan;
      if (hasChangedPlan) {
        history.push('/payments/success');
      }
    }
  }
```

For strange reason when component mounted almost immediately was redirecting me to `/payments/success` route even though values in reducer didn't change.

That's because at that point:

```
this.props.subscription.plan !== subscription.plan
```

was the same as

```
NaN !== NaN
```

which would always return `true` even though from my perspective nothing had changed.

Now I thought that hey: whenever `react-redux` id doing shallow compare in `shouldComponentUpdate` - if these NaN props are included - it will always return `true` when in fact nothing has changed.

I'm not sure if `React` also compares props while reconciliation or on some other process but that would also be a problem. I know `PureComponent` does shallow compare of props.

I would like to know am I on the right track, and should I never use NaN as default values in `React` or `Redux`.

Comment: it's definitely not an anti-pattern. An anti-pattern is common behavior that is wrong. An example of a common anti-pattern in react is storing props in initial state. I've never heard of using NaN as a default value so I'd hesitate in calling it a pattern. Pedantry aside, `null` or `''` are safer default values because, counter-intuitively, `NaN === NaN` will always return false, where as `null === null` will always return true and same for `''`.

Comment: @RobbieMilejczak yeah "NaN === NaN will always return false" that's what tripped me off. A big part of working with React is comparing props. Especially when it comes to optimization. Thanks for recap of anti-pattern ;)

Comment: Here's how to think about `NaN` in order to make sense of `NaN != NaN`: `NaN` represents any value than is *Not a Number*. The only fact known about this value is that it's something other than a number. Hence, it's impossible to know if two different values that are both something other than a number are equal to each other. E.g. `"Hello"` and `"Good bye"` are both `NaN` but they're not equal to each other.

Answer (score 2):

It is very inadvisable, NaN follow several tricky rules like:

```
NaN === NaN;        // false
Number.NaN === NaN; // false
isNaN(NaN);         // true
isNaN(Number.NaN);  // true
```

Also, semantically it means "Not A Number", which is weird.

Answer (score 1):

I'd set an initial value of a number to `0` (because `0` won't influence the possible calculations including that value in any way). Your code also becomes more readable then, and type declaration may serve as documentation, while having `NaN` as a value is very confusing.

The special case is using numbers as enums (i.e. in your case I think you're doing it with `payment_method: number`). I would create a special enum for the *bottom value* of a given set (most often `-1` is used in such cases).